# Getting error in gadgets.io.MethodType.PUT , getting error No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: javascript

i am getting error  No content to map to Object due to end of input why i don't know

```
var data2={description:"from micro app"};

//var json_upload = JSON.stringify({name:"RoleByAnil55", securityDomain:{"id": "domin000000000000001","name": "world"}});
var json_upload=JSON.stringify(data2);

var parameters = {};
parameters[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.HEADERS] = {"Content-Type" : "application/json","sabacertificate" :apiCertificate};
parameters[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD]= gadgets.io.MethodType.PUT;

parameters[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA] = json_upload);
gadgets.io.makeRequest("https://qadb-api.xyz.com/v1/role/roles000000000001946", callback, parameters);

function callback(obj) {
    alert(obj.text);
};
return 0;
```

Comment: And what have you tried to find the error? Obviously, your code does not contain such an error message and we have no clue what `gadgets.io` is and which API you are posting to

Comment: http://dev.groupdock.com/tutorials/todo-application.html      see this site